# sar + why sar not displayed the real disks under DEV section

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, block-device, sar

we have Linux machine with 2 disks - sda and sdb  ( sda is the OS )

```
lsblk  -d -e 11,1
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0    2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda    8:0    0  150G  0 disk
sdb    8:16   0   70G  0 disk /GHT
```

when we do `sar -d` , we get

```
12:00:01 AM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
12:10:01 AM   dev8-16      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:10:01 AM    dev8-0      0.12      0.07      1.93     16.87      0.00      0.48      0.28      0.00
12:10:01 AM  dev253-0      0.01      0.07      0.04      8.00      0.00      0.38      0.37      0.00
12:10:01 AM  dev253-1      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
12:10:01 AM  dev253-2      0.12      0.00      1.89     15.53      0.00      0.51      0.23      0.00
12:20:01 AM   dev8-16      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

we can see that DEV devices not displayed as sda or sdb ( disks )

so how to know which is sda or sdb ?

is it possible in some way to use sar, and displayed the real disks - sda or sdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From man:

> -d
>
> Report  activity  for  each block device<....>Device names may also be pretty-printed if option -p is used
>
> -p
>
> Pretty-print device names. Use this option in conjunction with option -d.  By default names are printed as dev m-n where m and n are the major and minor num-
>                 bers for the device.  Use of this option displays the names of the devices as they (should) appear in /dev. Name  mappings  are  controlled  by  /etc/syscon-
>                 fig/sysstat.ioconf.

```
 sar -p -d 1 1


07:16:35 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
07:16:36 PM       sda     13.00      0.00    120.00      9.23      0.04      3.08      1.38      1.80
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_root     15.00      0.00    120.00      8.00      0.05      3.07      1.27      1.90
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_swap      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_home      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```